# IE ignoring conditional comment when I use server name

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a web page with the following code in it:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
Welcome to IE 8
<![endif]-->
```

I am logged onto the server, and if I hit the page in IE 8 via the URL `http://localhost/login` I see the message. However, if I use the URL `http://myserver/login` (where `myserver` is the Windows name of the server I am logged into), the page displays and functions normally, except that the message is not displayed.

If I do a View Source, I see the code as I expect it -- the comment displays in the source. (OK, I'm really trying to load a conditional style sheet and it is not being loaded when I use the server name, but this simple example shows the same result).

Any ideas how to exit this new trip to IE bizarro-land?

Comment: That DO sound bizarre! Rendering should take place client side and just using a text string like here shouldn't raise any particular security issues... (Mostly security things when it comes down to differences between local and production) Just by interest, what DOCTYPE do you declare?

Comment: I am using `<!DOCTYPE html>` since this is a HTML 5 page. It displays correctly when hosted on 2 other servers. In fact, I can hit an external site that hosts it from the same server I am having problems with and it displays correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Page Settings, do you have 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' checked?  It's all [explained in this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/06/17/compatibility-view-and-smart-defaults.aspx).

Comment: Yes, that's it...thanks a million. I'll have to work with the IT staff at this customer to set the policy right.

Comment: IE compatibility view is a terrible solution! Compatible with WHAT? Good you solved it anyway!

Comment: Holy crap, that is the most short sighted thing that Microsoft has done in a very long history of short sighted things.  What happens when I want to write an intranet application that works properly in IE8 or IE9?  I can't, because everybody in the company will only see it in IE7 compatibility mode!

Comment: @PaulTomblin It's a chicken and egg thing - at the time most corporate customers would have avoided upgrading if the upgrade broke all the intranet sites that only worked in IE6/7.  If you are in control of the corporate intranet you can change everyone's settings through group policy.

Comment: @robertc, that would make sense if I could override it on my web page.  But you can't, because it ignores X-UA-Compatible.  So I have no way to write a modern web app on my intranet until every other web page on the intranet is ready to work on the latest IE, which they never will be.

Comment: @PaulTomblin You don't need to override it on your web page when you're in control of the whole network. On your intranet: set all the other web servers to send a header of `X-UA-Compatible` with a value of `IE=7`, disable the intranet setting with group policy and write your modern web app.

Comment: Ok, so as a web developer working on an app for one team of a large company, I can either 1) write as if everybody is on IE 7, or 2) get every other of the hundreds of thousands of web pages on the company intranet to change, and get the sysadmins to change a policy setting for the tens of thousands of employees.  You first.  Let me know how that goes.  In the meantime, I'm lobbying my boss to allow me to put up a banner that says "I see you're using IE.  Please change to Firefox or Chrome or this is going to suck."

Comment: @PaulTomblin You don't have to get 'hundreds of thousands of web pages' to change, you just have to change the server settings which, if they're IIS, can also be done through group policy.  The number of users and pages is irrelevant.  It's a couple of settings in a couple of scripts.  I'm not sure why you're getting all snarky with me about this; I don't work for Microsoft, I can't change their policy, I'm just providing you with options for working around it.

Comment: It's a stupid default policy.  Ok, so instead of changing hundreds of thousands of individual pages, I have to get the owners of a few dozen servers that don't belong to my group to agree to change a setting, as well as getting the sysadmin group to agree to a change to the group policy.  Yeah, that's no better.  There should be a way for the individual page to asset that it's standards compliant, and `X-UA-Compatible` is the logical place to do it.

Comment: @PaulTomblin OK, fine, what do you expect complaining to me about it is going to achieve?

Comment: Just confirming that there is no solution to this stupidity that will actually work in the real world.