# IE9 throws my page in IE7 document mode and <!DOCTYPE html> gets commented out

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9, ie-compatibility-mode

My webpage has the following doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The above line is the very first line on my HTML page.
These are no extra spaces or comments before this line.
Still the page goes in IE7 document mode and `<!DOCTYPE html>` 
gets commented out when i check the html page using developer tools.

I know that I can force a certain document mode by including the following meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

But I am not supposed to use this, niether I am supposed to go to tools and change the compatibility view settings (Tools -> Compatibility view settings).I have also checked whether the document is valid HTML5 document using a HTML5 validator.

Some solutions I searched were of CSS causing this problem ie. beacuse of using Type 1 font (Helevetica). I checked my css and nowhere we are using this font.

Basically I need to know what are the reasons that is causing this unusual behaviour.
Is it some css or javascript that is causing this.

EDIT : as mentioned in one of the comments I tried loading a simple html page as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>

   <title>Hello Wrold</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>hello world!!</div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

It is behaving the same way. Page loads in IE7 document mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168288/page-stuck-in-quirks-mode

Comment: @NathanLee I have already checked this link. I have read almost all the questions related to IE compatibility mode. And the doctype is properly written and I know the meta tag solution as well. I need to know reasons if any other than what I have mentioned in the question. And solutions for those reasons.

Comment: The soundest advice is here: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8. It is unlikely there are any further reasons. The commenting of the doctype is an effect of being in IE7 mode, not a cause.

Comment: Is this on an intranet server? And are there other things you've tried; e.g. do other HTML files (simpler ones, but still with the HTML5 DOCTYPE) behave the same way? If so, add that info to the question. By the way, I'm a bit worried about your statement that you're not supposed to change IE's compatibility view settings. What are those settings now?

Comment: @MrLister There is this provision in IE to change the compatibility view settings. This helps make websites that were created for older  browsers, especially Internet Explorer 6 and 7, look better in IE 9 which renders web pages closer to the standards and thus differently from those versions of IE. You can go to these settings Tools -> Compatibility view settings and by default Dislay intranet sites in compatibility is checked. We dont want our users to go and uncheck this setting to view our page properly.

Comment: Do you have 'Display intranet sites in compatibility mode' checked?

Comment: @robertc Yes it is checked and unfortunately I am not supposed to change it

Comment: Then you have no way of forcing standards mode on your intranet, the browser setting will always override.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE ignoring conditional comment when I use server name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779451/ie-ignoring-conditional-comment-when-i-use-server-name)

Comment: You can solve a lot of quirks by explicitly putting them in your stylesheet. For instance the margins and paddings on HTML, BODY, paragraphs in table cells etc. That will make the page look a lot les "quirky". It won't solve everything though; there's still the little matter of IE7 mode not knowing about the latest HTML features...

Comment: @MrLister I tried a simple html file, with just body and html5 doctype. It still goes in IE7 document mode

Answer (score 1):

Check your html file and make sure there is no BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the beginning of the document. This can cause problems in some browsers. In order to check, use something like Adobe Dreamweaver or Notepad++.
Open file in ANSI mode in notepad and check if there are characters before, delete them and save as UTF-8 without bom (option when saving in notepad++)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that this is just the way IE DevTools works when it emulates different document modes. It doesn't depend on the content of your page.