# Doctype is commented out in Internet explorer 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have red all the questions and answers on this issue. Still it didn't help. In my IE 11, the doctype is always commented out.

I think IE is Rendering the page in compatibility view. I am assuming this because some html properties such as border-radius are red underlined as if IE 11 not recognizing it, so I think that IE is not Rendering the page in Standard mode, though in developers tool Edge is selected.

I have chekced all the compatibility Settings. Everythings is unchecked and fine.

The Website was previously running on IE8 and was optimised for that.

Comment: like this `<!DOCTYPE html>` or `<!-- DOCTYPE html -->`

Comment: like <!-- DOCTYPE html -->

Comment: The site is running on Intranet and not on internet

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My IE11 browser comments out the DOCTYPE so it looks like: <!-- DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat" -->

Comment: A peculiar behaviour that I've observed is that if I Ctrl+F5 many times in rapid succession, IE eventually "forgets" to comment out the doctype and the page renders properly

Answer (score 4):

Could you please post a code snippet of your current HTML document?

I would try to do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I added the following meta-tag to my webpage and it works for me:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I found it on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785222/ie9-throws-my-page-in-ie7-document-mode-and-doctype-html-gets-commented-out)

Comment: Ensure the meta-tag is in the head and you do not start with other tags first (i.e. script and link)

Comment: @GideonMulder, this was it. I had meta tag but it was still not working fine, your comment saved me. Thanks much :)